# Plotting KMeans Clustering of Text Data in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have code that cleans some text data, vectorizes it with TfidfVectorizer, and is run through a KMeans Model. Everything is working ok, with the exception of actually plotting the clusters.

I am not totally understanding the output of TfidVectorizer

For example:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['column 1'].values.astype('U'))

print(X)

(0, 36021)  0.17081171474660714

(0, 36020)  0.17081171474660714

(0, 36011)  0.13668653157547714
```

Can someone help me understand how to actually plot the clusters? I'm a little stuck on where to go for here. Or is there a better vectorizer to use for KMeans?

Also, when I look at the cluster centers I am seeing weird output, it ends up with a few thousand columns like below... Its a relatively small dataset of about 3000 records of text

```
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

[[8.71020045e-05 8.71020045e-05 8.71020045e-05 ... 1.34902052e-05
  1.34902052e-05 1.34902052e-05]
```

Here is some sample code for the clustering as recommended:

```
df = pd.read_csv('----------------.csv')

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['column 1'].values.astype('U'))

true_k = 10
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)

model.fit(X)

print('Top Terms Per Cluster:')
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print('cluster %d' % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    print

print(model.cluster_centers_)
print(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

`TfidfVectorizer` transforms each row of your data into a sparse vector of floats, where the dimension of the vector is equal to the size of the vocabulary determined by `TfidfVectorizer` (so you get a matrix that is `n_docs x n_vocab`). Typically the vocabulary will be much larger than the number of documents. KMeans computes cluster centers in this high dimensional space. If you want to visualize these clusters in 2d or 3d, you need to use some form of dimensionality reduction to on both the Tfidf vectors and the KMeans centers. Since the Tfidf matrix is sparse, `TruncatedSVD` fitted on the Tfidf matrix is probably what you want.

Here's a toy example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

docs = [
    "aa bb cc dd ee ff",
    "aa bb cc gg hh ii",
    "dd ee ff gg hh ii",
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
km.fit(X)

tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2).fit(X)
projected_docs = tsvd.transform(X)
projected_centers = tsvd.transform(model.cluster_centers_)
```

Comment: I was trying to fit TruncatedSVD on X which is the vectorized output but am consistently getting the following error:  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'TruncatedSVD'. any suggestions ?

Comment: That error looks like you're passing the TruncatedSVD object as a parameter to some function. I've added an example of how to use it above.

Comment: Thanks! this is a big help.  Why do you choose 2 components? does anything happen to the components that are not used? For example, when i print cluster centers it returns a few thousand columns. With components = 2, what about all of those others?  I guess I'm just confused on the actual output that I see

Comment: The number of components is arbitrary, but 2 is good for plotting. Per the documentation for KMeans (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), the cluster centers have dimensionality (n_clusters, n_features) when the input has dimensionality (n_samples, n_features).